# How to draw a line in Delphi on an FMX canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, paintbox

This is with Delphi Berlin 10.1 Update 2

The following works (I get a line drawn):

```
brush := TStrokeBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, TAlphaColors.Lightgray);
brush.Thickness := 2;
with Canvas do
begin
    BeginUpdate;
    DrawLine(PointF(10, 10), PointF(100, 10), 1, brush);
    EndUpdate;
end;
```

The following does not work:

```
with Canvas do
begin
    BeginUpdate;
    Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    Stroke.Thickness := 2.0;
    DrawLine(PointF(10, 10), PointF(100, 10), 1);
    EndUpdate;
end;
```

Why can't I use the 2nd one? How can I get it to work, or should I stick to creating a stroke brush as in the first example?

I've included a minimal application:

main.pas

```
unit main;

interface

uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects;

type
    TMainForm = class(TForm)
        PaintBox: TPaintBox;
        procedure OnPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
    private
        { Private declarations }
    public
        { Public declarations }
    end;

var
    MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TMainForm.OnPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
    with Canvas do
    begin
        BeginUpdate;
        Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
        Stroke.Thickness := 2.0;
        DrawLine(PointF(10, 10), PointF(100, 10), 1);
        EndUpdate;
    end;
end;

end.
```

main.fmx:

```
object MainForm: TMainForm
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Caption = 'Form1'
    ClientHeight = 480
    ClientWidth = 640
    FormFactor.Width = 320
    FormFactor.Height = 480
    FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
    DesignerMasterStyle = 0
    object PaintBox: TPaintBox
        Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 16.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 609.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 449.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        OnPaint = OnPaint
    end
end
```

test.dpr:

```
program test;

uses
   System.StartUpCopy,
   FMX.Forms,
   main in 'main.pas' {MainForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
    Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: The code in your second example is fine.  Please show a [mcve].  Are you perhaps trying to draw outside the `Paint` method or `OnPaint` handlers?

Comment: `Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;` may be needed on Android, since it is `bkNone` by default. On Windows the default value is `bkSolid`.

Comment: I've added the minimal files needed to show the issue

Comment: @imekon Then certainly your code works fine for me (10.1 Seattle, windows) - are you compiling for android?  ios?  mac?

Comment: Windows 32 bit debug or Mac OS X

Comment: @LURD `Stroke.Kind` seems to be `None` in D 10.1 Berlin as default. Adding as you suggested worked in my test. Maybe you should put it up as an answer.

Comment: @J... Also to confirm your observation, it works without setting `Stroke.Kind` in D 10 Seattle, but in 10.1 Berlin it needs to be set

Comment: You really need to stop using with

Comment: I was just beating my head over this same problem, except I already was assigning `Stroke.Kind` yet still nothing. Turned out I was dumb and used `TColorRec.Red` instead of `TAlphaColors.Red`. It still compiles and runs, but has the wrong value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Earlier versions of Delphi had different default values for [Stroke.Kind](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBrush.Kind) depending on platform.

Since Delphi 10.1 Berlin, the default value seems to be `None`for all platforms. (Thanks @TomBrunberg)

To make the line appear, set `Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;`

*Note: Tested on Windows 8.1*

---

I created a new Metropolis FMX application as well, where the drawing worked without setting the `Stroke.Kind`. Can't explain that though.

---

A similar report was filed at QP, [RSP-16313
The Canvas.DrawLine doesn't work at Windows XP (32 bit) forms](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16313). Here the problem manifests on Windows-XP but not on Windows-7.

Comment: Bingo! Adding Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid was the answer. But why was such an odd default added?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps the value is not persistant at all, but varies depending on context. Anyway, always setting it to solid before writing, works in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

it's very strange that first case is work.

You should use stroke brush.

And you Should use BeginScene and EndScene instead of BeginUpdate and EndUpdate. This fragment works perfect:

```
  Brush := TStrokeBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, TAlphaColors.Black);
  Brush.Thickness := 2;
  with Canvas do
  begin
    BeginScene();
    DrawLine(PointF(10, 10), PointF(100, 10), 1, Brush);
    EndScene;
  end;
```

Comment: The question states that using a separate Brush works and asks why using DrawLine without such a Brush does not work. Using BeginScene/EndScene in an OnPaint event is not needed.

Comment: This doesn't work - even if I use BeginScene/EndScene: with Canvas do
      begin
        BeginScene;
        Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
        Stroke.Thickness := 2.0;
        DrawLine(PointF(10, 10), PointF(100, 10), 1);
        EndScene;
      end;